# A error while using case next to order by

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-order-by

The code is supposed to give me the table ordered after if value 'isOnline' == 1 then 'onlineTime', if 'isOnline' == 0 then onlineTime + current milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC (isOnline is TINYINT, onlineTime is BIGINT)

```
SELECT * FROM onlinecountertable 
ORDER BY 
    CASE `isOnline`
        WHEN 0 THEN `onlineTime`
        WHEN 1 THEN (onlineTime + (ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000))
        ELSE `onlineTime` 
    END
    DESC LIMIT 30
```

But if I use the query above, it gives me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE -1
    END)
    DESC LIMIT 30 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6
```

Comment: The error MySQL reports there appears not to have come from the posted code, as you don't have `ELSE -1` here, nor a `LIMIT 0,25` and MySQL is not substituting a value for `onlineTime`. Check the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
    WHEN 1 THEN (onlineTime + (ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000))
```

by this

```
    WHEN 1 THEN (onlineTime + ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000))
```

Cheers ;-)